# Other protocols than HTTP on Samsung TV?

Tags: http, tcp, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I just looked through the [Devleopment Guide for Samsung TVs](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/). As far as I can see, most Samsung TV apps are "just" web pages based on HTML, Javascript and CSS. Because of this, I can do HTTP connections With the XMLHttpRequest.

Is there any way to do non-HTTP connections? Actually I have a simple TCP/IP based protocol which I want to use with a simple "smart" Samsung TV app.

Comment: Write a webservice that translates to the other protocol?

Answer (score 2):

As i know you can use TCP in PNACL modules, like example:

[TCP Socket in PNaCl application](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/index.html?Foldername=d25&Filename=index.html)

Also Samsung TV started to support Websocket from 2013 platform in web based applications and in PNACL applications:

[WebSocket in PNaCl application](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/index.html?Foldername=d3&Filename=index.html)